# Why we can't use two structs (or classes) of different types but with exactly the same members interchangeably?

Tags: c++

Assume that I have two structs (or classes) called `Student` and `Employee`, and `Student` and `Employee` have exactly the same members.

My question is, why can't I do the following:

```
Student s;
Employee e;

Student* p;
p = &s;
p = &e;  // this will cause a compilation error
```

Comment: If you wanted this to work, what was the point of making both classes and having them represent separate types?

Comment: A `Student` is not an `Employee`.

Comment: I think C actually allows this, just not C++

Comment: fwiw, structs *are* classes

Comment: Welp, it may seem innocuous to interchange a student and an employee. But I'd prefer it if nuclear launch sequences were not interchangeable with something that just contains the same fields.

Comment: If your goal is to perform functions based on how the internals are similar, then you are looking for templates and [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9d38f217ecd2b50)

Comment: You can if you use the same class or struct, say, Person for both.

Answer (score 4):

Because C++ is [nominally typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), not [structurally typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system)

Answer (score 2):

Because they are different types.

A type is more than its members and a types interface is more than its member functions. Consider you have

```
void enroll(Student& s);
void promote(Employee& e);
```

Those are free functions, yet they are part of the types interfaces. Both functions can be prooven to be correct by looking only at the definition of `Student` or `Employee` respectively.

Not being able to use the two types interchangably is good, because we do not want to enroll an employee for an university course and we do not want to promote a student to a CEO.

It is not a limitation, but rather a feature that helps to turn logic errors (enroll an employee, or promote a student) into compiler errors.

Comment: Is the example that you showed considered an advantage of nominal type systems and a disadvantage of structural type systems?

Comment: @Christopher I wouldnt call it advantage/disadvantage, because each has its own strengths. This summarizes it quite weill: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system#Comparison

Comment: Can we say that your example is a disadvantage of structural type system, however, this doesn't mean that structural type system is bad and should never be used, it just means that each type system have its advantages and disadvantages. For example: your example is a disadvantage of structural type system in the case you showed only, however it may be an advantage in other cases because it allows more flexibility when working with types?

Comment: @Christopher its just a feature. If you do want to enroll an employee to a univerity course and you do want to promote a student to CEO, because hey why not, then it is no "advantage" that you cannot do that

Comment: I guess you are right that your example doesn't show how using types interchangeably is a disadvantage of structural type systems. But if we have let's say a `Stack` type and a `Queue` type, and the `Queue` type have the same members as the `Stack` type (plus some more members), and then we called `push_to_stack()` and passed a `Queue` object to it, then `push_to_stack()` would modify the state of the `Queue` object in a way that it shouldn't be modified in. However, in a language that uses a nominal type system, we would not be allowed to pass a `Queue` object to `push_to_stack()`.